# Android Studio generating AIDL java file with wrong package name in generatedJava folder

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, aidl

I am attempting to use AIDL for different processes to access the same service.  I have been following the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl) on how to create AIDL files.  The problem I am having is that when `gradle` generates the AIDL java file, it puts in the wrong package structure, thus my application cannot find the file.

I have downloaded multiple example apps and they all generate the file in the proper package, and both mine and their build.gradle flies are the same.

```java
// IMyAidlInterface.aidl
package com.example.myapplication;

// Declare any non-default types here with import statements

interface IMyAidlInterface {
    /**
     * Demonstrates some basic types that you can use as parameters
     * and return values in AIDL.
     */
    void basicTypes(int anInt, long aLong, boolean aBoolean, float aFloat,
            double aDouble, String aString);
}
```

`build.gradle` (MyApplication)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`build.gradle` (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

It should be `com.example.myapplication`, but it is generated as `Users.landon.ITU.MyApplication.app.src.main.aidl.com.example.myapplication`.

[image: structure]

Is there something that I need to change in the default settings that android studio uses to properly generate the files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `build.gradle` (app),  you need to change `buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"` too `buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"`.  `29.0.0` seems to have broken how AIDL files are generated.